# How do I convert HTML markup to just raw text?

Tags: html, ruby, tags, nokogiri

What's the easier way to remove all the tags from a `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment` keeping only the text separated by spaces?

I want to transform:

```
Hello<br>My name is McOmghall
```

into:

```
Hello My name is McOmghall
```

My solution is:

```
Nokogiri::XML.fragment(html_text).children.to_a.flatten.select { |node| node.class == Nokogiri::XML::Text}
```

and then concatenate that array putting spaces between each element, but I think it's suboptimal and not very clear.

---

EDIT:

This is my final solution:

```
Nokogiri::XML.fragment(html_text).xpath('.//text()').map(&:text).join(' ')
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the original doc or only the output as mentioned format? That's a confusion..

Comment: Only the output, but I don't mind modifying the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
root = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="test">Hello<br>My name is McOmghall</div>')
root.at_css('#test').text
# => "HelloMy name is McOmghall"
root.at_css('#test').xpath('.//text()').map(&:text)
# => ["Hello", "My name is McOmghall"]
p root.at_css('#test').xpath('.//text()').map(&:text).join(' ')
# => "Hello My name is McOmghall"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Nokogiri` has a very handy method `text?` for this case:

```
html = "Hello<br>My name is McOmghall"    

Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html).children.select(&:text?).join(' ')
# => "Hello My name is McOmghall"
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no space before or after the `br`, there won't be a space in the text

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML 'Hello<br>My name is McOmghall'
doc.text
#=> "HelloMy name is McOmghall"
```

It's easy to add a space after each `br` though:

```
doc.search('br').each{|br| br.after ' '}
doc.text
#=> "Hello My name is McOmghall"
```